# Please Help me to add share Wallpaper code from firebase

Tags: java, android

I stored url with id in firebase. I am using viewpager2 in xml. I want to share image or want to add share option in that. How can I do this.

```
public void onApplyImage(int position, Bitmap bitmap) {
            WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

            try {
                manager.setBitmap(bitmap);

                Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this, "Wallpaper successfully set ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this, "Failed to set as wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onShareImage(int position, Bitmap bitmap) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to share is that first set you image to a ImageView and then use the following code to share you image.

```
ImageView content = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewy);    
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Uri imageUri= Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
content, "title", "discription"));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```